Middle school geometry problem about a triangle inscribed in a circle with very particular properties
I'm reading my old middle school math textbook and I came across a problem which I can't make heads or tails of.
I'll translate from my language (Italian) as best as I can:

In a circle of given radius $r$, inscribe a triangle $ABC$ such that $ \widehat{BAC} = 60^\circ$ $(AB > AC)$ and that the altitude drawn from vertex $A$ is $\cong r$. Extend side $BA$ of a segment $AD \cong AC$ and demonstrate that straight line $DC$ is tangent in $C$ to the circumference and is parallel to the bisector of the $\widehat{BAC}$ angle.

Fact is, I can't even begin to imagine how to construct such a problem. In fact, I tried with some apps (mainly GeoGebra) but I can't produce the initial picture. Either I come up with a trivial triangle or the sides, altitude, angle and radius do not match with what's needed. So I can't go on from there.

I can get the picture based on your description. Can you substantiate why you're having difficulty?

I really... Don't know, I just don't get it. It's like I've hit a wall. I mean, I get drawing a rough picture without caring about getting the lengths right, but then I think I'm missing something I need to solve the problem. So I was trying to have a precise picture. But I can't get an altitude equal to the radius and a 60° angle without flattening the triangle. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

@ValentinoStopponi: Consider $\triangle A'BC$ with $A'$ on the perpendicular bisector of $BC$; since $\triangle A'BC$ is isosceles (why?) and $\angle A=\angle A'$ (why?), it must be that $\triangle A'BC$ is actually equilateral. So, reverse the thinking: Start with equilateral $\triangle A'BC$, and let $A$ be on the circumcircle (guaranteeing $\angle A=60^\circ$) such that the perpendicular to $BC$ matches the circumradius; there are only two points $A$ can be (why?), and the restriction $AB>AC$ reduces the possibilities to one point. This gives $\triangle ABC$. Can you continue from there?

Sorry, @Blue, but I don't get why the angle A' should be congruent to A only based on your premises. A' could be anywhere on the bisector, and even if it is on the circumference, I don't get why it should be = A.

@ValentinoStopponi: Whoops! ... I should've fully described my mental image: $\triangle A'BC$ shares its circumcircle with $\triangle ABC$. Then (for $A'$ on (major) arc $BAC$ of that circle), the Inscribed Angle Theorem guarantees $\angle A=\angle A'$.

Ok, I think I got it, thanks! I'll go on from there myself. So, just to be clear: are you agreeing with DynamoBlaze's 30-60-90 or RobinSparrow's not-quite-30-60-90 answer? If I got it correctly, the only solution is 30-60-90.  @RobinSparrow, I think your answer is the same with different methods, but your measurements are just a little skewed by the application you're using.

@ValentinoStopponi: I'm agreeing that $\triangle ABC$ is $30^\circ$-$60^\circ$-$90^\circ$.

@ValentinoStopponi: I second the 30-60-90, sorry for the confusion. The construction I proposed is sound, but had a misclick error when I made it so the angles were slightly off, it yields the 30-60-90.

You say you cannot do it without flattening the angle. That might be a sign that the angle needs to be flat. It is sometimes the case that points defined differently turn out to be the same point - for example, the intersection of the perpendicular bisectors and the circumcenter. I will now prove that you must have the altitude meet $BC$ at $C$ itself.
Call $O$ the center of the circle and $E$ the foot of the perpendicular from $A$ on $BC$. Call as $F$ the foot of the angle bisector of $A$ on $OE$. Then $AF$ makes an angle of $A/2$ with the line $BD$. Now, the triangle $ADC$ is an isosceles triangle with a middle angle of $180^{\circ}-A$, so $\angle ADC=A/2$. So $BD$ makes an angle of $A/2$ with the line $DC$. So the line $DC$ is parallel to $AF$.
Now as $AEC$ is right-angled, $\angle EAC=90^\circ-C$. Using the fact that the angle at the centre is twice the angle at the circumference, we have $\angle BOA=2\angle BCA=2C$. Then as the triangle $BOA$ is isosceles, we have $\angle BAO=90^\circ-C$.
From this we have $\angle OAF=\angle EAF=C-60^\circ$. So $AF$ is the angle bisector of the angle $OAE$ as well. Since $AO=AE$, the triangle $OAE$ is isosceles, so $AF\perp OE$. But then, as $AF\parallel DC$, we have $DC\perp OE$.
Now, by the law of sines $AB=2r\sin C$. But as $AEB$ is a right angled triangle, we have $AE/AB=\sin B$. As $AE=r$, this becomes $AB=r/\sin B$. So $r/\sin B=2r\sin C$. So we have $2\sin B\sin C =1$.
We now use the product to sum formula $2\sin B\sin C=\cos(B-C)-\cos(B+C)$. Letting $B=120^\circ-C$, we get $1=\cos(120^\circ-2C)-\cos60^\circ$. So $\cos(120^\circ-2C)=1/2$. From here $120^\circ-2C=\pm60^\circ$. We get $C=30^\circ,90^\circ$. As we have $AB\gt AC$, you get $120^\circ-C\lt C$, so $C\gt 60^\circ$. So $C=90^\circ$.
But then $C=E$, as $AC\perp BC$ - the flattening I suspect you were talking about. So $DC\perp OC$. So $DC\perp OC$. So $DC$ is tangent to the circle at $C$.
Now, having solved this, you can construct a triangle with angles $30-60-90$.

No, I think this answer makes sense (I'm still trying to process the last part - sorry I'm a little rusty on trig): it matches with the "flattening" I was talking about (sorry for the ambiguous term, but I think you nailed what I meant, @DynamoBlaze).

A moment's reflection shows the 30-60-90 qualifies, my construction had an error and now yields the 30-60-90, sorry for the confusion!

I cannot tell if the OP actually wants the problem solved, but it is clear the construct is challenging, which makes sense if the OP is resurrecting old knowledge.
Here is the picture, and one way to construct it. Draw a circle of any radius, call it $r$ with center $O$. At any point, call it $B$, draw a tangent line. At any point $B'$ on that line, construct equilateral $BB'B''$ inward towards the circle. This cuts an angle of $60$ at $B$. Extend this line if necessary until it meets the circle at $C$. Now any point on the major arc subtending $BC$ will subtend $60$, as desired. From $B''$ draw a perpendicular $B''H=OB$, and at $H$ draw a line parallel to $BC$. Where this line cuts the circle, mark $A$. Then at $A$ we have an angle of $60$ and an altitude of exactly the radius of the circle. I think you can develop the rest of the construct from there...
EDIT: The initial construct had an error in the Geogebra diagram, it should have yielded a 30-60-90 but was slightly off. Remaking yields the 30-60-90. Many of us would know the 30-60-90, from its special properties, immediately satisfies the demands of the OP. But if the problem were changed to most any other angle, we would not know what to expect. This construct creates the needed triangles for any desired angle (the marked one), including 60, which is what is shown. I'm putting the correct diagram below the original diagram.



Wait, I don't get how AH can be an altitude of ABC in A. It doesn't fall on BC... Or am I missing something?

It falls just beyond $C$ on $BC$. This is normal, it happens with every obtuse triangle.

Ok, then I can't see how it is guaranteed to be congruent to the radius.

The altitude is the distance $B''H$, which is constructed to be the radius $r=OB$. Also note that @Blue's construct yields exactly the same triangle that I am describing in this answer, it's a different way to arrive at the same construct.

@RobinSparrow: There's something off with your construction. Referring to my comment to the question, w/ $A'$ the pt where the perpendicular bisector of $BC$ meets the circumcircle (making $\triangle A'BC$ equilateral), one easily shows that the distance from $A'$ to $BC$ is $3r/2$. Consequently, the locus of candidate points $A$ at distance $r$ from $BC$ is the perpendicular bisector of $OA'$; thus, our specific $A$ is one of the pts where this line meets the circle: these are the "other" vertices of inscribed rectangle with side $BC$. Ultimately, $\triangle ABC$ should be $30$-$60$-$90$.

@Blue: The construction logic is right, but I made the figure as I was going out the door and I must have misclicked somewhere, over dinner I began wondering how two qualifying triangles could be possible since the 30-60-90 has to be a possible triangle. Remaking it now yields the 30-60-90. As of course it should have. =)

In any triangle with circumradius $r$, distance of vertex $A$ to orthocenter $H$ is $2r \cos A$. In particular, for $A = 60^\circ$, $ AH = r$. This means $H$ lies vertically below $A$ at distance equal to circumradius.
According to given question, $H$ is other end of altitude from $A$. It is well known $H$ lies on the triangle iff the triangle is right and $H$ is vertex containing the right angle. Here $C=H$ and it follows $BAC$ is $30 - 60 - 90$ triangle, in this order.
Rest of the construction can be followed easily from the diagram.

Notice $A$ being equidistant from $C,D$ as well as centre $O$, is centre of circle through $O,C,D$ which form another triangle right angled at $C$. Thus $CD$ is tangent to circumcircle of $ABC$.

Revised.
We first prove a general lemma about triangles with a $60^o$ angle.
Lemma:
Suppose $\triangle ABC$ is inscribed in circle $c1$ with center $O$ and radius $r$. If $\widehat A = 60^o$ then the triangle's orthocenter $J$ is on circle $c2$ with center $A$ and radius $r$.
Proof:
Let $c1$ and $c2$ intersect at $M$ and $N$. We have $\overset\frown{AM} = \overset\frown{AN} = 60^o$ (why?), and therefore $\widehat{ACM} = \widehat{ABN} = 30^o$. Let $CM$ meet $AB$ at $K$, and $BN$ meet $AC$ at $P$. Then $\triangle ACK$ and $\triangle ABP$ are right triangles. $CK$ and $BP$ are altitudes in $\triangle ABC$, and their intersection $J$ is the orthocenter.
Note the angle $\widehat{MJN} = \widehat{KJP}$. If $J$ is inside $\triangle ABC$ then $\widehat{MJN} = 120^o$, and if $J$ is outside $\triangle ABC$ then $\widehat{MJN} = 60^o$ (why?). This means that the loci of $J$ is a circle passing through $M$ and $N$, and that $M$ and $N$ mark a $120^o$ arc on this circle. This circle is of course $c2$.

We can now proceed with the solution of the problem, considering its additional constraints.
Solution
Let $H$ be the foot of the altitude from $A$ to $BC$. Because $AH = r$, we know that $H$ is on circle $c2$. But from the above lemma we know that $J$ is also on $c2$. And since $H$ and $J$ are on the same radius from $A$, we have to conclude that $H$ and $J$ are eventually one point. It follows that $\triangle ABC$ is a right triangle with $\widehat C = 90^o$ and $\widehat B = 30^o$. As a result, $AH = AC = r$ and $AB = 2r$ is a diameter of $c1$. It can also be seen that $\triangle ACO$ is equilateral.
From here, the reader should easily be able to prove that $\triangle ABC$ and $\triangle ODC$ are congruent and therefore $OC \perp DC$.


Wait. Who said that the angle A in ABH is 60°? I mean, of course it is, but it's not stated beforehand. You're proceeding assuming it is. Or am I missing something?

Oh sorry I made a mistake! I will revise or remove this answer.

@ValentinoStopponi revised!
